# Convert String to date in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to convert string to date in Tableau. String looks like this:

> Thursday, 26 June 2014 08:11:46 o'clock BST

I tried to use Dateparse, but I get Null values:

```
DATE(DATEPARSE("dd/MMMM/YYYY",[Posting Date]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to strip out extras like weekday name, o'clocks , timezone etc .

All these can be achieved simply as below `regex` . After that you can format as per `dateparse`

```
DATEPARSE("dd MMMM yyyy" , REGEXP_EXTRACT( [Date],'(\d+\s+\w+\s+\d+)' ))
```

explaining regex :

```
1. \d+ : extract one or more occurrence of numerical digits 
2. \s+ : extract one or more occurrence of space chars 
3. \w+ : extract one or more occurrence of alphabet chars 
4. \s+ : extract one or more occurrence of space chars 
5. \d+ : extract one or more occurrence of numerical digits
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a simple one line way to do this that I could see. I made fields to find each of the date parts with regex_extract and then reassembled the parts with dateparse()

*Date Day*
    `REGEXP_EXTRACT([Value], '([0-9]{2})')`

*Date Month*
`REGEXP_EXTRACT([Value],'(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)')`

*Date Year*
    `REGEXP_EXTRACT([Value], '([0-9]{4})')`

*Date Parsed*
    `DATEPARSE("dd/MMMM/yyyy", [Date Day]+"/"+[Date Month]+"/"+[Date Year]`

[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUAri.png)

One word of caution is that regex does not work with all datasources in Tableau